# Why my php files on my website show source in chrome?

Tags: php, website, hosting, source-code

I just get some troubles with my php files. I host my website from my computer and I get an index.html file which link to other php files for my website, in firefox when I go from the index files to php files its working fine but with chrome when I go to the php files links I just get the source of the php file display on the webpage. Why?

[image: this is what my webpage looks like]

Comment: what if you try a simpler php snippet tag like `<?php  (new line) ?>`    Also , I see you're going to a `www` address, probably you're not running the web server yourself. You could contact your web provider and ask them if they even support php, and if they say yes, then show them what's going on and ask them what's happening

Comment: What webserver technology are you using? Apache? IIS?

Comment: @barlop the DNS record for that domain is pointing to a domestic IP address in France. It is highly likely the OP is self-hosting.

Comment: @Burgi  By "domestic" do you mean only one IP allocated, rather than a block? And suppose he was self hosting and he's in france,and ran a small business?   i'm sure most small businesses don't use multiple public IPs. (though granted most wouldn't self host).  Can you elaborate on domestic - how you concluded that, and why that'd suggest to you not self hosting. He does say " I host my website from my computer"

Comment: @barlop it appears to belong to an ISP that provides broadband to homes. https://who.is/dns/alexandreamiel.in

Comment: We should probably take this to chat, I think you may have misunderstood me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the configuration of your webserver. Perhaps you have some server-side code that responds to different browsers in different ways? To confirm, you're accessing your server via `http://localhost/...` and not via `file:///...`?

[EDIT] If you have configured your domain `www.example.com`, could it be that Firefox is redirecting you from `example.com` to `www.example.com` automatically, whereas Chrome isn't? In other words, could there be different behaviour from your server depending on whether the user accesses via these two different URLs? I think that Firefox may do this redirection automatically if you don't explicitly type the `http://`.

Comment: Look at the first tab, it says `www.` so it's not file:///  And to say it's a problem with the configuration of his web server doesn't tell him what to do so isn't very useful especially not as any kind of answer. And it assumes it's his web server, which isn't necessarily the case, especially when it's `http://somedomainotherthanlocalhost`

Comment: "I host my website from my computer"...